# Make a component render in more than one page - Routes Angular 13

Tags: angular, routes, auth-guard

I have the following routes, and I need to render the Conditional component in some specific routes, but the shared component in all routes. How can I do it?

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: "someroute", component: ConditionalComponent,
children: [{ path: '', component: SharedComponent }],

}
];

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to have

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: "someroute",
        component: ConditionalComponent
    }
];
```

And in your app.component.html you should have

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<shared-component></shared-component>
```

Comment: there is any other way?

Comment: Alternatively, you can just put

<shared-component></shared-component> 

in each of your conditional components templates.